# How to use the MongoTemplate get the result in order?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In mongoDB I want to get a result in order, but when I use the sort method, the Error

> com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 96 and
>   error message 'Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort
>   operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an
>   index, or specify a smaller limit.' on server localhost:27017     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:722)    at
>   com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:711)    at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:471)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711)
>     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
>     at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826)  at
>   com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:130)     at
>   com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:77)     at
>   com.linkyoyo.wmlink.service.impl.DataShowServiceImpl.getAllDateRWDByTowerId(DataShowServiceImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   com.linkyoyo.wmlink.service.impl.DataShowServiceImpl.getSpeedDateRWDByTowerId(DataShowServiceImpl.java:49)
>     at
>   com.linkyoyo.wmlink.service.impl.DataShowServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75f7873c.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   com.linkyoyo.wmlink.service.impl.DataShowServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eaf288ce.getSpeedDateRWDByTowerId()
>     at
>   com.linkyoyo.wmlink.controller.DataShowControllerTest.allData(DataShowControllerTest.java:44)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

was happened.

```
public MongoCursor<Document> getAllDateRWDByTowerId(Integer towerId) {

    MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("rwd");

    FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find().sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.descending("date")));

    return fi.iterator();
}
```

I attempt some different methods, the same error always happen.I don't know why it happened and how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM
```

Mongo [Sort Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations):

> If MongoDB cannot use an index to get documents in the requested sort
>   order, the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus
>   a small overhead, must be less than 32 megabytes.

The solution would be to add an index to the sort field. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.index-and-collections.index) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add a index for object's field "date" , 
if you don't add it , mongo will load a lot of data from harddisk in memory 
and cause a exception.

if you know index , in some database index was implement by B+ data struct，
it's a hard-disk friendly data struct ，use less memory.